# Jquery only targeting every other select option?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm working on learning Javascript and jQuery, and have come across a problem in the example code below that I wrote which I can't seem to figure out the cause of. I was attempting to write a script that would cause the second select dropdown to mirror the selected option in the first dropdown.

I'm curious to know why my current code seems to be targeting only every other select option. I'm newly learning Javascript/jQuery so I'm sorry if this is an obvious answer, but I would really appreciate if someone could explain to me **why** this code is targeting only half of my select options rather than all of them, in addition to how to fix it, so that I can learn from this mistake.

```
  <style>
  #sweets {
    color: red;
  }
  </style>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>

<select id="sweets" >
  <option value="Chocolate">Chocolate</option>
  <option value="Candy">Candy</option>
  <option value="Taffy">Taffy</option>
  <option value="Caramel">Caramel</option>
  <option value="Fudge">Fudge</option>
  <option value="Cookie">Cookie</option>
</select>
<select id="target">
  <option value="Chocolate">Chocolate</option>
  <option value="Candy">Candy</option>
  <option value="Taffy">Taffy</option>
  <option value="Caramel">Caramel</option>
  <option value="Fudge">Fudge</option>
  <option value="Cookie">Cookie</option>
</select>

<script>
$( "#sweets" )
  .change(function () {
    var str = "";
    $( "option:selected" ).each(function() {
      str += $( this ).val();
    });
    $( "#target" ).val( str );
  })
  .change();
</script>
```

Also, here is a JSFiddle of the same code.
https://jsfiddle.net/2xnmr0pa/1/

Comment: Think about what `$( "option:selected" ).each` does: it iterates over _all options that are selected_, even if they are in a _different_ `select` list. The value you are trying to set, therefore, is something like `"TaffyCandy"` instead of `"Taffy"`. Such a value doesn’t exist. The value is always two values, whenever _two_ options are selected.

Comment: Ok, that totally makes sense to me now. Thank you!

Comment: As you’re new to JS, I should suggest using [`console.log`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Console/log) and debugging your code with the [browser console](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/q/8525) to find unexpected behavior in your code yourself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is in the following code:

```
$( "option:selected" )  // selected options from ANY list on the page
```

This selects all selected options from **BOTH** lists, not just the first one.

Therefore, each time you select a value on your first list, you also take the currently selected value from the other list, append them both and then try to set that as the new value of the second list.

The fix is simple, just limit your selection of selected options to the first list by changing the above code to:

```
$( "#sweets option:selected" ); // selected options in the #sweets list
```

Or you could use the fact that jQuery switches the context (the value of `this`) in attached functions to the element that the function was attached to and just find its selected option:

```
$(this).find('option:selected')
```

Comment: Thanks for explaining why this doesn't work! I understand the issue now and the cause of it, the value of the combined select options were not equal to a single select option, so I need to target the #sweets option rather than all option fields, because this grabs both dropdowns values.

Comment: No problem, glad to help!

Answer (score 2):

All you should need is:

```
$("#sweets").change(function () {
    var str = $(this).val();
    $("#target").val(str);
}).change();
```

If you log the str value when you use .each you can see sometimes it has multiple values joined together making a selection impossible.

Answer (score 1):

Change your code as shown below, no need to .each()

```
$( "#sweets" )
 .change(function () {
 //var str = "";
 // $( "option:selected" ).each(function() {
 //    str = $( this ).val();
 //});
  var str = $( this ).val();
 $( "#target" ).val( str );
})
.change();
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are curious to know how this would look in pure JavaScript:

https://jsfiddle.net/ryanpcmcquen/eys05d3u/

```js
document.getElementById("sweets").addEventListener('change', function (e) {
  var sweets = e.target;
  var str = "";
  str += sweets.querySelector('option:checked').value;
  document.querySelector("#target").value = str;
});
```

```css
#sweets {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<select id="sweets">
  <option value="Chocolate">Chocolate</option>
  <option value="Candy">Candy</option>
  <option value="Taffy">Taffy</option>
  <option value="Caramel">Caramel</option>
  <option value="Fudge">Fudge</option>
  <option value="Cookie">Cookie</option>
</select>
<select id="target">
  <option value="Chocolate">Chocolate</option>
  <option value="Candy">Candy</option>
  <option value="Taffy">Taffy</option>
  <option value="Caramel">Caramel</option>
  <option value="Fudge">Fudge</option>
  <option value="Cookie">Cookie</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Interesting. Thank you for posting! upvoted. one thing I noticed however, is that with this method, it seems the second dropdown no longer can be directly changed on it's own.

Comment: @Josh979, thanks for noticing that, fixed now with a conditional.  ;^)